# D2L - Facing Issue for LE -.1.7

Tags: desire2learn

I am facing an issue while fetching the participant’s first name from class list data. The LMS version that we have is - v10.3.0.

We are accessing the class list data from external system using web service exposed by LMS. For this we are using the API - http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-classlist-

The le version that we are using now is 1.3 for retrieve the participant’s data like user name, user Id etc.

As per updates, we can also retrieve the participant’ first name and last name for le version 1.7+ & LMS version - v10.3.0.

But when, we changed the le version 1.3 to 1.7, we are getting an error. I had also tried for our customer LMS instance, but getting the same result.

So, I am looking for your support to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation page tells you everything you need to know about Valence versions:

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#current-release-changes

On this page you will notice that for LE 10.3 the last supported API version is 1.4.

New API versions are being rolled out in conjunction with our Continuous Delivery model (currently 10.5.2).